# how to solve a blog url on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I built a website with a PHP script and after installing I see a bug in the script. For reference I attach the [link of the website blog](https://cardwisechoice.com/blog-details/125), here I want to modify the link - blog-details/ this number 125.

[image: URL example]

I just want to replace the number after the `/` and change it according to my blog post title. How can I solve the issue?

I try modifying the route:

```php
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
Route::get('/about', [HomeController::class, 'about'])->name('about');
Route::get('/faq', [HomeController::class, 'faq'])->name('faq');
Route::get('/blog', [HomeController::class, 'blog'])->name('blog');
Route::get('/blog-details/{contentDetails}', [HomeController::class, 'blogDetails'])->name('blogDetails');
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/contact', [HomeController::class, 'contact'])->name('contact');
Route::post('subscribe', [HomeController::class, 'subscribe'])->name('subscribe');
Route::get('{content_id}/{getLink}', [HomeController::class, 'getLink'])->name('getLink');
Route::get('/{template}', [HomeController::class, 'getTemplate'])->name('getTemplate');
```

But I was not able to solve it.

Comment: And what is the issue? I see no issue at all. And one super personal recommendation, I see all your routes use `HomeController`, the idea is to use CRUD, so you should have `index`, `show`, `create`, `store`, `edit`, `update`, and `delete`. You have your own name and all on the same controller, that is not good. Example: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

Comment: Pass a different value, other than 125?

Comment: can you show the view from where the route get click? and also the controller

Comment: Might be helpful https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-key

Comment: You just can google “laravel slug” and find this: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable

Comment: thanks all but i did not get it yet .. try to figure it out